# GPU OOM: Hyperparameter Tuning loop with varying models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm grid-searching hyperparameters using itertools.product() and overwriting the model variable with each loop. However, at 2nd iteration, it crashes due to Out Of Memory:

```
import itertools
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.losses import sparse_categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import Adam

hyperparameters = {
'lr': [1e-3, 1e-4],
'model': [model1, model2]
}

hps, values = zip(*hyperparameters.items())
for v in itertools.product(*values):
  cur_hps = dict(zip(hps, v))
  model = cur_hps['model'](input_shape = (256, 256, 3))

  optim = Adam(lr = cur_hps['lr'])
  model.compile(optimizer = optim,
                loss = categorical_categorical_crossentropy,
                metrics = ['accuracy'])

  train_gen = myDataGenerator() # returns Sequence

  model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                      epochs = 5,
                      use_multiprocessing = True,
                      workers = 8)
```

I've tried ending the loop with:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
del model
keras.backend.clear_session()
```

But to no avail, which makes it cumbersome when more than 50 combinations are to be tested. The models has different architectures.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are 2 possible causes:

1. Memory is not released after training the previous network
2. The given model is simply too big

For the first case, check [Keras: release memory after finish training process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005147/keras-release-memory-after-finish-training-process)

For the second case, try decreasing the `batch_size` in your data generator and see whether it fixes the problem. Alternatively, use multiple GPUs or change the architecture so that it can fit into memory.