# Keras in R: freeing up memory after multiple training sessions

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, memory, tensorflow2.0

I am training multiple models in R. After a while, I run out of memory.

From rudimentary googling, the tensorflow sessions seems to hold things in memory after the objects have been overwritten in R. This has been a problem that others have encountered, however I have seen no answers that help for keras in R in particular.

[Keras: release memory after finish training process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005147/keras-release-memory-after-finish-training-process/52354943)

[Tensorflow2.0: GPU runs out of memory during hyperparameter tuning loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188831/tensorflow2-0-gpu-runs-out-of-memory-during-hyperparameter-tuning-loop?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I've tried running these commands after each loop:

`rm(model)`

`k_clear_session()`

`tf$compat$v1$keras$backend$clear_session()`

but these problems persist. Any ideas on how to release the memory Keras uses?

I'm running this code on a laptop, and I'm pretty sure I don't have a GPU.

Comment: Running `gc()` (maybe even repeatedly) does not help? Sometimes R is sluggish with garbage collection and needs a kick in the butt.

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible example?

Comment: @t-kalinowski no i cannot.

Comment: It's going to be hard for anyone to help you without a reproducible example...

Answer (score 1):

I recall having some memory issues in R (can't remember if it was with keras or something else), but one or a combination of the following should help:

```
remove(list=ls()) #remove your objects

gc() #garbage collection

.rs.restartR() #restart the R session (clean the memory but doesn't detach your packages)
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll give some of these a go. I'm familiar with how R behaves when it runs out of memory, but the Keras package seems to work differently. The out of memory errors are in Python, for one.