# How to free up memory after each iteration of GridsearchCV that tunes tensorflow/keras models?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am doing hyperparameter tuning for neural network using GridSearchCV on tensorflow models using KerasRegressor.
At the end of the grid search, the memory consumed is high and not released. I want to release memory after each model is evaluated by gridsearch so that the memory leak is not accumulated. I searched for the solutions at many places including stack overflow and tried the following code in the beginning of my model build method.import gc

keras.backend.clear_session()
del model
gc.collect()
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()

I see that these does not help to release the memory back to free pool. Can anyone help pls ?

Comment: Hi @Rajaram, Could you please refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005147/keras-release-memory-after-finish-training-process) and let us know if it helps or not. Thank You.